# protect battery on thinkpad T490 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad T490 on Ubuntu 18.04. I want to protect my battery (the tlp stuff with max charge 80 and start charge 75).

However, it looks like I have some problems:

```
~$ sudo tlp setcharge START_CHARGE 70
Error: ThinkPad battery features not available.
```

I think this is due to problems with tp-sampi and / or tpacpi-bat:

```
~$ sudo tlp stat
...
+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (kernel module 'acpi_call' load error)
```

After googling, it seems that `tp-smapi` does not work on thinkpads from versions *30 and over and `tpacpi-bat` should be the solution to use instead. I cannot find more help about if / how I should set up `tpacpi-bat`. Any tips / instructions? :)

Comment: Not listed in the bug list https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues  from the maintainer: https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

Comment: @K7AAY do you think I should open an issue there? :)

Comment: Opened an issue there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a [discussion with the package author and maintainer](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/427) (many thanks to him for his patience with my n00bness), the solution was to update to the PPA version 1.2.2 (I guess newer may work as well):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms tlp
```

After that things start to work:

```
~$ sudo tlp-stat
--- TLP 1.2.2 --------------------------------------------
...

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = active (data, thresholds)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (kernel module 'acpi_call' load error)
tp-smapi   = inactive (ThinkPad not supported)
...
```

and the battery levels can be updated:

```
~$ sudo tlp setcharge 70 80
Setting temporary charge thresholds for BAT0:
  start =  70 (no change)
  stop  =  80 (no change)
```

leading to:

```
~$ sudo tlp-stat
...
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold         =     70 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold          =     80 [%]
...
```

Note that if you want the update to survive reboot, you need to update the configuration file at `/etc/default/tlp` by uncommenting / modifying the lines 355-356 (you will need to open as root and overwrite readonly protection, for example in vim you need `:w!` ):

```
350 # Battery charge thresholds (ThinkPad only, tp-smapi or acpi-call kernel module
351 # required). Charging starts when the remaining capacity falls below the
352 # START_CHARGE_THRESH value and stops when exceeding the STOP_CHARGE_THRESH value.
353 # Main / Internal battery (values in %)
354 # Default: <none>
355 START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=70                                                                                         
356 STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=80
357 # Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable battery (values in %)
358 # Default: <none>
359 #START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=75
360 #STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=80
```

For more details:

https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#chargethresholds

Comment: Default thinkpad threshold :               
                                                          
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold         =     20 [%]   and 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold          =     20 [%]

Comment: I was able to set the charge thresholds in terminal but I don't even have a `/etc/default/tlp` on Ubuntu 20.04 after `sudo apt-get install acpi-call-dkms tlp` for T420 and later.  Do I need to add linrunner still?  I set it at 30 80 and it's still charging at 84 atlhough `sudo tlp-stat` shows the correct numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For THINKPAD E14 default threshold :

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold = 20 [%] /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold = 20 [%]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms tlp
```

we can change threshold to 60/80 by  `sudo tlp setcharge 60 80`

Can check by `sudo tlp-stat`