# lenovo t490 draining battery - TLP not helping ( ubuntu 18.04 )

Tags: power-management, laptop, lenovo, battery, thinkpad

I would need your help. As much as I don't want to get back to Windows if I was not able to resolve this, I would be (most likely) forced to :(

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad t490, ubuntu 18.04 and my battery is draining deadly fast. I can usually use it (nothing extraordinary - just general surfing, web coding, ... ) for about 4 hours - which is desperate. I would expect 7-8 at least.

I followed this tutorial [askubuntu - protect battery on ThinkPad t490](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166885/protect-battery-on-thinkpad-t490-ubuntu-18-04) but it didn't help :(

is there something else I can do to improve my battery? Please see my TLP conf file attached

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# tlp - Parameters for power saving
# See full explanation: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

# Hint: some features are disabled by default, remove the leading # to enable
# them.

# Set to 0 to disable, 1 to enable TLP.
TLP_ENABLE=1

# Operation mode when no power supply can be detected: AC, BAT.
# Concerns some desktop and embedded hardware only.
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC

# Operation mode select: 0=depend on power source, 1=always use TLP_DEFAULT_MODE
# Hint: use in conjunction with TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT for BAT settings on AC.
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=0

# Seconds laptop mode has to wait after the disk goes idle before doing a sync.
# Non-zero value enables, zero disables laptop mode.
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2

# Dirty page values (timeouts in secs).
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60

# Hint: CPU parameters below are disabled by default, remove the leading #
# to enable them, otherwise kernel default values are used.

# Select a CPU frequency scaling governor.
# Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver:
#   powersave(*), performance.
# Older hardware with acpi-cpufreq driver:
#   ondemand(*), powersave, performance, conservative, schedutil.
# (*) is recommended.
# Hint: use tlp-stat -p to show the active driver and available governors.
# Important:
#   powersave for intel_pstate and ondemand for acpi-cpufreq are power
#   efficient for *almost all* workloads and therefore kernel and most
#   distributions have chosen them as defaults. If you still want to change,
#   you should know what you're doing! You *must* disable your distribution's
#   governor settings or conflicts will occur.
#CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=powersave
#CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave

# Set the min/max frequency available for the scaling governor.
# Possible values strongly depend on your CPU. For available frequencies see
# the output of tlp-stat -p.
#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
#CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=0

# Set energy performance hints (HWP) for Intel P-state governor:
#   performance, balance_performance, default, balance_power, power
# Values are given in order of increasing power saving.
# Note: Intel Skylake or newer CPU and Kernel >= 4.10 required.
CPU_HWP_ON_AC=balance_performance
CPU_HWP_ON_BAT=balance_power

# Set Intel P-state performance: 0..100 (%).
# Limit the max/min P-state to control the power dissipation of the CPU.
# Values are stated as a percentage of the available performance.
# Requires an Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver.
#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_BAT=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=30

# Set the CPU "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable, 1=allow
# Requires an Intel Core i processor.
# Important:
# - This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings
# - A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it
#CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
#CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0

# Minimize number of used CPU cores/hyper-threads under light load conditions:
#   0=disable, 1=enable.
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1

# Kernel NMI Watchdog:
#   0=disable (default, saves power), 1=enable (for kernel debugging only).
NMI_WATCHDOG=0

# Change CPU voltages aka "undervolting" - Kernel with PHC patch required.
# Frequency voltage pairs are written to:
#   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/phc_controls
# CAUTION: only use this, if you thoroughly understand what you are doing!
#PHC_CONTROLS="F:V F:V F:V F:V"

# Set CPU performance versus energy savings policy:
#   performance, balance-performance, default, balance-power, power.
# Values are given in order of increasing power saving.
# Requires kernel module msr and x86_energy_perf_policy from linux-tools.
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=power

# Disk devices; separate multiple devices with spaces (default: sda).
# Devices can be specified by disk ID also (lookup with: tlp diskid).
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"

# Disk advanced power management level: 1..254, 255 (max saving, min, off).
# Levels 1..127 may spin down the disk; 255 allowable on most drives.
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the hardware default for the particular disk.
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"

# Hard disk spin down timeout:
#   0:        spin down disabled
#   1..240:   timeouts from 5s to 20min (in units of 5s)
#   241..251: timeouts from 30min to 5.5 hours (in units of 30min)
# See 'man hdparm' for details.
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the hardware default for the particular disk.
#DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC="0 0"
#DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT="0 0"

# Select IO scheduler for the disk devices: cfq, deadline, noop (Default: cfq).
# Separate values for multiple disks with spaces. Use the special value 'keep'
# to keep the kernel default scheduler for the particular disk.
#DISK_IOSCHED="cfq cfq"

# AHCI link power management (ALPM) for disk devices:
#   min_power, med_power_with_dipm(*), medium_power, max_performance.
# (*) Kernel >= 4.15 required, then recommended.
# Multiple values separated with spaces are tried sequentially until success.
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"

# Exclude host devices from AHCI link power management.
# Separate multiple hosts with spaces.
#SATA_LINKPWR_BLACKLIST="host1"

# Runtime Power Management for AHCI host and disks devices:
#   on=disable, auto=enable.
# EXPERIMENTAL ** WARNING: auto will most likely cause system lockups/data loss.
#AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
#AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on

# Seconds of inactivity before disk is suspended.
AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT=15

# PCI Express Active State Power Management (PCIe ASPM):
#   default, performance, powersave.
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=default
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=default

# Radeon graphics clock speed (profile method): low, mid, high, auto, default;
# auto = mid on BAT, high on AC; default = use hardware defaults.
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=default
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=default

# Radeon dynamic power management method (DPM): battery, performance.
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery

# Radeon DPM performance level: auto, low, high; auto is recommended.
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto

# WiFi power saving mode: on=enable, off=disable; not supported by all adapters.
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=off
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=on

# Disable wake on LAN: Y/N.
WOL_DISABLE=Y

# Enable audio power saving for Intel HDA, AC97 devices (timeout in secs).
# A value of 0 disables, >=1 enables power saving (recommended: 1).
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1

# Disable controller too (HDA only): Y/N.
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y

# Power off optical drive in UltraBay/MediaBay: 0=disable, 1=enable.
# Drive can be powered on again by releasing (and reinserting) the eject lever
# or by pressing the disc eject button on newer models.
# Note: an UltraBay/MediaBay hard disk is never powered off.
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC=0
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
# Optical drive device to power off (default sr0).
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"

# Runtime Power Management for PCI(e) bus devices: on=disable, auto=enable.
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto

# Exclude PCI(e) device adresses the following list from Runtime PM
# (separate with spaces). Use lspci to get the adresses (1st column).
#RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="bb:dd.f 11:22.3 44:55.6"

# Exclude PCI(e) devices assigned to the listed drivers from Runtime PM.
# Default when unconfigured is "amdgpu nouveau nvidia radeon" which
# prevents accidential power-on of dGPU in hybrid graphics setups.
# Use "" to disable the feature completely.
# Separate multiple drivers with spaces.
#RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="amdgpu nouveau nvidia radeon"

# Set to 0 to disable, 1 to enable USB autosuspend feature.
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1

# Exclude listed devices from USB autosuspend (separate with spaces).
# Use lsusb to get the ids.
# Note: input devices (usbhid) are excluded automatically
#USB_BLACKLIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"

# Bluetooth devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
USB_BLACKLIST_BTUSB=0

# Phone devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude (enable charging).
USB_BLACKLIST_PHONE=0

# Printers are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
USB_BLACKLIST_PRINTER=1

# WWAN devices are excluded from USB autosuspend:
#   0=do not exclude, 1=exclude.
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1

# Include listed devices into USB autosuspend even if already excluded
# by the blacklists above (separate with spaces).
# Use lsusb to get the ids.
#USB_WHITELIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"

# Set to 1 to disable autosuspend before shutdown, 0 to do nothing
# (workaround for USB devices that cause shutdown problems).
#USB_AUTOSUSPEND_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN=1

# Restore radio device state (Bluetooth, WiFi, WWAN) from previous shutdown
# on system startup: 0=disable, 1=enable.
# Hint: the parameters DEVICES_TO_DISABLE/ENABLE_ON_STARTUP/SHUTDOWN below
#   are ignored when this is enabled!
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

# Radio devices to disable on startup: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple devices with spaces.
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on startup: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# Separate multiple devices with spaces.
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_STARTUP="wifi"

# Radio devices to disable on shutdown: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# (workaround for devices that are blocking shutdown).
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on shutdown: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
# (to prevent other operating systems from missing radios).
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="wwan"

# Radio devices to enable on AC: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_AC="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to disable on battery: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_BAT="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Radio devices to disable on battery when not in use (not connected):
#   bluetooth, wifi, wwan.
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_BAT_NOT_IN_USE="bluetooth wifi wwan"

# Battery charge thresholds (ThinkPad only, tp-smapi or acpi-call kernel module
# required). Charging starts when the remaining capacity falls below the
# START_CHARGE_THRESH value and stops when exceeding the STOP_CHARGE_THRESH value.
# Main / Internal battery (values in %)
#START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=75
#STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=80
# Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable battery (values in %)
#START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=75
#STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1=80

# Restore charge thresholds when AC is unplugged: 0=disable, 1=enable.
#RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT=1

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# tlp-rdw - Parameters for the radio device wizard
# Possible devices: bluetooth, wifi, wwan.

# Hints:
# - Parameters are disabled by default, remove the leading # to enable them
# - Separate multiple radio devices with spaces

# Radio devices to disable on connect.
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_LAN_CONNECT="bluetooth wifi wwan"
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_WIFI_CONNECT="bluetooth wwan"
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_WWAN_CONNECT="bluetooth wifi"

# Radio devices to enable on disconnect.
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_LAN_DISCONNECT="wifi wwan"
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_WIFI_DISCONNECT=""
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_WWAN_DISCONNECT=""

# Radio devices to enable/disable when docked.
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_DOCK=""
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_DOCK=""

# Radio devices to enable/disable when undocked.
#DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_UNDOCK="wifi"
#DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_UNDOCK=""
```

here is upower output:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                02DL008
  serial:               764
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 24 Nov 2019 06:46:40 PM PST (89 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              41.28 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         52.37 Wh
    energy-full-design:  50.45 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.335 W
    voltage:             12.098 V
    time to empty:       3.6 hours
    percentage:          78%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1574592400  78.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1574592400  11.335  discharging
```

My NVIDIA card is disabled:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
```

Drivers' info:
[image]

Is there something I am missing? I don't believe it has such lousy power management :(

If there is additional info needed, please let me know guys, I will edit and provide asap

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPU power management extension helped a lot :) my CPU was on turbo and highest performance.. setting it to energy saver of quiet mode gave me some more time on battery (not significantly but an hour or so more) :) definitely worth a try!!