# TLP 1.3.1 issue in Thinkpad T490 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad, tlp

I removed the Windows 10 Pro on my brand new Thinkpad T490 and installed my favorite Unbuntu (18.04). Well the transition was not as euphoric as I expected.

While trying to find a work around for a well-known battery drainage problem in Thinkpad T490 with Ubuntu, I tried the fix in [protect battery on thinkpad T490 - Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167078), but I cannot get it to work. The only change in my case from the suggested fix is the TLP version that has changed from 1.2.2 to 1.3.1.

Output from `sudo tlp-stat -b`:

[image: screenshot of terminal]

One can see that both `natacpi` and `natacpi-bat` are inactive.

Comment: On my Thinkpad T400s I only need tp-smapi active for TLP to work. I installed that with `sudo apt install tp-smapi-dkms`, which you seem to have done. You might also have to enable the lines `TLP_ENABLE="1"` and `TPSMAPI_ENABLE=1` in your tlp.conf to make it work.

Comment: I made these changes (TLP_ENABLE="1" and TPSMAPI_ENABLE=1) in my tlp.conf, but it made no difference!

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was a kernel version that no longer supports natacpi. Starting with kernel 4.17 tpacpi-bat gets superseded by a new, native kernel API called natacpi (contained in the ubiquitious kernel module thinkpad_acpi). I updated to kernel 5.3 using `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04`, and it works now:

Output from `sudo tlp-stat -b`:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gbwK.png)